# Npgsq 4.0 with entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I had a project with ef6 and npgsql 3.2, all worked perfect. But when i updated npgsql to 4.0 and attempt to save entity i got an exception:

```
"InnerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException",
        "Message": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.NotSupportedException",
            "Message": "Parameters with NpgsqlDbType.Unknown are no longer supported. If you're writing enums as strings, see the section on unmapped enums in the documentation.",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": null,
            "HelpURL": null,
            "StackTraceString": "   в Npgsql.TypeHandlers.UnknownTypeHandler.ValidateObjectAndGetLength(Object value, NpgsqlLengthCache& lengthCache, NpgsqlParameter parameter)\r\n   в Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ValidateAndGetLength()\r\n   в Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ValidateParameters()\r\n   в Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__101.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
            "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            "ExceptionMethod": "8\nValidateObjectAndGetLength\nNpgsql, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7\nNpgsql.TypeHandlers.UnknownTypeHandler\nInt32 ValidateObjectAndGetLength(System.Object, Npgsql.NpgsqlLengthCache ByRef, Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter)",
            "HResult": -2146233067,
            "Source": "Npgsql",
            "WatsonBuckets": null
        },
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesInternalAsync>d__31.MoveNext()",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": "8\nMoveNext\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator+<UpdateAsync>d__0\nVoid MoveNext()",
        "HResult": -2146233087,
        "Source": "EntityFramework",
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    }
```

Model code:

```
[Table("entities")]
public class EntityDto 
{
    [Column("id")]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("alias")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("display")]
    public string Display { get; set; }

    [Column("dbtable")]
    public string DbTable { get; set; }

    [Column("assembly")]
    public long Assembly { get; set; }

    [Column("autogenerated")]
    public bool Autogenerated { get; set; }
}
```

Table of entity was generated perfect by automigration.
At the same time, data selection works correctly.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this, it's an actual behavior change in Npgsql 4 that didn't take into account the EF6 provider. Can you please open an issue about this on http://github.com/Npgsql/npgsql.

*EDIT*: Reverted the behavior change, everything should work again in 4.0.0-preview2 which should be released very soon.